# Anchor links not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, firefox, hyperlink, anchor

I'm building a site in Chrome and just discovered none of my anchor links work in IE or Firefox.

I'm coding it in Wordpress like:

Menu link:

```
http://dev.legendpower.com/contact/#Offices
```

Anchor:

```
<a name="offices" class="anchor"><h3 style="text-align: center;"><span 
style="color: #000000;">Legend offices.</span></h3></a>
```

Strangely, there is one page on the whole site where the anchor link is working, and I can't for the life of me figure out what if anything there is different on that page. The coding there goes like...

Menu Link:

```
http://dev.legendpower.com/markets/#Casestudies
```

Anchor:

```
<a name="casestudies" class="anchor"><h3 style="text-align: center;"><span 
style="color: #000000;">Case studies.</span></h3></a><p></p><p>The case 
studies below are just a subset of our customer-base. We’ve installed over 
200 Harmonizers in almost every type of building. Click on an image to 
access the case study.</p>
```

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: Hi Jill.  Check for case-sensitivity issues.  "Casestudies" isn't the same as "casestudies".   Note also that it shouldn't be necessary to even use "<a name=" anymore---modern browsers will navigate to any id attribute on the page without you having to explicitly insert anchors.  So, if you have "<p id='myParagraph'>", a link to "page.php#myParagraph" would take you to that spot on the page.

Now, all THAT said, there's no reason you can't continue to use anchors if you don't have unique ID's.

Comment: Thanks - funny originally it wasn't working unless I capitalized them in the link, even though the names aren't capitalized. I tried using ids and it wasn't working - thought maybe it was my theme perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

hope you doing well...

Please use this snippet

```
    <a href="http://dev.legendpower.com/contact/#Offices" name="casestudies" 
    class="anchor">The case studies below are just a subset of our customer-
    base. We’ve installed over 200 Harmonizers in almost every type of 
    building. Click on an image to access the case study.</a>
```